# URLLoader loads multi files and the result order is the same as call load()

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, urlloader

Since URLLoader is async, how to make sure the order of data from server side is the same as the loader.load() call? In other words, the data order in totalResults is the same order of url-related content?

Following is code snippet:

```
1.for each(var url in urls) {
    loadData(url);
}
2.private function loadData(url:String):void {
    var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    urlLoader.load(request);
}
3.private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    var result:Object = loader.data;
    totalResults.push(result);// suppose totalResults is Array and a property in the class.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend `URLLoader` class functionality.

```
dynamic class DynamicURLLoader extends URLLoader { }
```

Then store data ( in your case probably `index` ) in loader object, before requesting:

```
 var urlLoader:DynamicURLLoader  = new DynamicURLLoader();
 urlLoader.index = ...
```

After response, retrieve that data ( in your case `index` ):

```
var loader:DynamicURLLoader = DynamicURLLoader(event.target);
totalResults[ loader.index ] = loader.data;
```

Answer (score 2):

you could either use [BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/) - it got this build-in. or you have to build your own queue, where one file is loaded after the other.

code snippet:

```
0.var queue:Array, totalResults:Array = [];
var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

1.for each(var url in urls) {
    loadData(url);
}

2.private function loadData(url:String):void {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    queue.push(request);
}

3.private function doQueue() {
    if (queue.length > 0) {
        var arr:Array = queue.splice(0,1);
        var req:URLRequest = arr[0] as URLRequest;
        urlLoader.load(req);
    }
    else {
        // queue done !
        trace(totalResults);
    }
}

4.private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    var result:Object = loader.data;
    totalResults.push(result);// suppose totalResults is Array and a property in the class.
    doQueue();
}
```

Comment: the BulkLoader is excellent, thanks. BTW, could you share your experience of finding such opensource?

Answer (score 1):

You can load each url sequentially one after the other in order like in the following example:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _urls:Vector.<String>;
        private var _counter:int;

        private var _data:Array;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _urls = Vector.<String>(["text1.txt", "text2.txt", "text3.txt" ]);
            _counter = 0;
            _data = [];

            loadNext();

        }// end function

        private function loadNext():void
        {
            var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(_urls[_counter]));

        }// end function

        private function onComplete(event:Event):void
        {
            _data.push((event.target as URLLoader).data);

            if (_counter++ == (_urls.length - 1)) trace("complete"); 
            else loadNext();

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

The methods `loadNext()` and `onComplete()` act as a loop. When `loadNext()` is called, an `URLLoader` object is instantiated and loads an url in the `Vector.<String>` object `_urls`. It uses the `_counter` object as a counter that is increment upon each `UrlLoader` object's "complete" event.

When the `onComplete()` event handler is called, it pushes the data loaded by the `URLLoader` object into an array called `_data`. Finally an if statement checks to see if all the urls have been loaded, if not, it increments the counter, if so, it executes the rest of the code in the application, in this case `trace("complete");`.

Comment: thanks, it works. However, it will have a poor performance if there are a lot of request, right?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use HTTPService, which allows you to use AsyncToken to determine which initial call resulted in which initial result? That way, you don't have to wait between calls (with the performance degradation that implies.) Here is some documentation about how it works with Remoting, which is similar http://flexdiary.blogspot.com/2008/11/more-thoughts-on-remoting.html . With HttpService, you get back the token as a result of the send() method.